# Programming an MCU with an unknown toolstack/SDK

Tags: microcontroller, flash

I want to add Wi-Fi functionality to existing circuitry on a PCB by wiring in an ESP8266. However, this requires me to reprogram the existing MCU on the board. I have identified the MCU as an SG8F080P Programmable Touch Sensor Controller manufactured by SigmaChip. However, I am unable to find any reference material for programming or flashing the chip. SigmaChip's [website](https://sigmachip.com/index.php/en/enproducts/enproducts-4/enproducts-4-2.html) is outdated and does not have a product page for this MCU. Even the products that do have their own page contain no resources for programming. I reached out to the email on their website about a week ago and have yet to hear back from them. I was somehow able to find the [datasheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jz27jhk09z7hem6/SG8F080P-spec-v1.1%28EASY%29.pdf?dl=0), but I am still at a loss for where to start. Does anyone know anything about programming without a known toolchain or SDK? Or am I better off ditching the chip and rewiring the PCB for a CAP1188?

Comment: why do you think that you can run code on the SG8F080P?

Comment: this is from page 3 of the document that you linked `program OTP ROM` .... i think that should answer your question

Comment: "this requires me to reprogram the existing MCU" - why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SG8F080P is a processor with OTP - One Time Programmable memory. So you can't reprogram the existing circuit.

More, even if you could re-program the memory, and want to integrate something else, you would need the entire source code for the original functionality, and it is very very unlikely that you can get it, ever. Their proprietary code is likely their biggest asset, likely contains some know-how to handle the touch sensors reliably, so they won't give it to you. So your whole starting premise is wrong.

The CAP1188 is not the MCU, it is a peripheral device. So your best option is start with something known, public, Raspberry-Pi Zero, Arduino, Particle Photon, and add the sensor chip, and the radio (if it is not already there). Basically, you need to start from scratch.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know the CAP1188 is not an MCU. I needed the touch sensing functionality from the original circuit as an input to the ESP8266, which I now know isn't possible. The reason I mentioned the CAP1188 is because I would be able to use it as a peripheral for the ESP8266. That is most likely what I will end up doing.